# Display single quotation mark in date format

Tags: groovy

So far I have used the following code to get the date of yesterday:

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today - 1
yesterday.format( '"yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59"' )
```

Result today: `"2021-02-25 23:59:59"`

---

Now I want to get the exact same result but instead of `"` I only want to have a **single quotation mark** looking like this: 
`'2021-02-25 23:59:59'`

Therefore, I tried mutliple ways to modify the code above for example:

```
def today = new Date()
def yesterday = today - 1
yesterday.format( '''yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59''' )
```

However, so far all my trials lead to this result: `2021-02-25 23:59:59` 
As you can see in this result there is no quotation mark at all.

What do I need to change to the result including the **single quotation mark**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the output you want:

```
yesterday.format( "''yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59''" )
```